# WPF open other Project

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have 3 WPF projects in my projectmap and i want to open the WPF Window of project 2 in project 1.

This is how it should look like but there is no "openProject2" after "As New".

```
Dim openProject2 As New openProject2
openProject2.Show
```

Why cant i make a new object of openProject2?

Comment: reference "project2" from "project1"; add namespace, e.g. `using project2;`; after that classes should be accessible

Comment: how to reference project 2 from project 1? -- if i type using i dont find project2

Comment: it is solution management, not coding: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx

Comment: Ok i added the reference. now i have to put the "code" in project 1 in a namespace and code of project 2 in the same namespace?

Comment: in proj1 you can use any names. but if you want to use smth from proj2 in proj1, then proj1 should import correct namespaces, existing in proj2, via `using`

Comment: @Raizzen: What's the name of the window class and what's the name of the second project?